# Only one node inside div - HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have looked something different from `.appendChild()` and `.innerHTML` but to work with `Image()` JavaScript objects.

I have 10 variables, `img[1,2,3,4...10]`, created with JavaScript (`new Image()`) to pre-load and it's OK, now I want to insert it into my div only one at time.

`innerHTML` returns something like `HTMLImageObject` and `appendChild()` won't work like I want.

My solution so far is:

```
document.getElementById("teste").removeChild(document.getElementById("teste").firstChild);
document.getElementById("teste").appendChild(img1);
```

Someone have any better ideas?

Comment: What do you mean : `Btw don't come to World Cup on Brazil unless you want to be stolen or dead ;-) great advice from one Brazilian`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please see [ask] for advice on how to ask a good question.  In your case, we need a lot better detail about how `appendChild` isn't working.  You should be able to append a new Image(); I've done it before.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I think his method works, he's just looking for a better solution

Comment: @AshishMishra please ignore that, it is irrelevant and was taken out of the question

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes, i'm just looking a better solution

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I do not want to append, I want to remove the previous node and insert another new node.

Comment: Provide your `snippet(code)` that you try for ?? @user3357575

Comment: replaceChild (oldNode,newNode);

Comment: How to mark SOLVED in my question? @ZachSaucier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `appendChild` use `replaceChild`. For example:

```
div.replaceChild(imgs[i], div.firstChild);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8bKy8/

Comment: Thanks! replaceChild is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

your way is pretty solid but maybe like this is easier to read.. also lastChild has a marginal performance advantage

```
var ele = document.getElementById('teste');

while(ele.lastChild) { 
    ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild)
}

ele.appendChild(img1);
```

http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild/15

you could also keep a reference to the element somewhere

```
var ele = document.getElementById('teste'), img = ele.lastChild;

ele.removeChild(img);
ele.append(img1);
```

if you have jQuery available you can use

```
$('#teste').clear().append(img1);
```

depending on the browser you are using you potentially also have access to the HTML5 Selector API as well even without jquery that may be an alternative to the document.element method

```
document.querySelector('#tests').first();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Comment: Thanks, querySelector is much better.